# loading a doubly linked list from a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, linked-list

I have a QueueList table:

```
{Id, Queue_Instance_ID, Parent_Queue_Instance_ID, Child_Queue_Instance_ID}
```

What would be the most efficient way to stuff this into a `LinkedList<QueueList>`? Do you think I can go lower than `o(n^2)`?

Comment: What more do you want to do the items than just putting them in the linked list? Adding an item in a LinkedList<T> is an O(1) operation, so adding n items is an O(n) operation.

Comment: I want to put them in the correct order. I am going to get a list in a random order if I just select them from the database.

Comment: Why would you get them in a random order if you select them? You'll undoubtedly get them sorted faster with the database than you will in code, especially if the table is indexed.

Comment: I assume by random he means that they are not necessarily linked in the same order of their IDs.

Comment: Also, if this is homework it needs to be tagged as such.

Comment: @Adam: I would be very hesitant to say he would "undoubtedly get them sorted faster with the database" than in code... that depends on a lot of factors, including the number of results, what type of index, what info is in the indx records. I can certainly imagine a situation where the db is worse.

Comment: ok then... give me a query that selects them in the correct order ;)

Comment: Ha, well here's a question for you: can any assumption be made about the queue ids? Is a "rank" kept for each queue? Or can a parent id / child id be any number relative to the child/parent id?

Comment: id - just a primary key for a list element(you should ignore this one)
queue_instance_id - linked list element value
parent_queue_instance_id - value of the parent element (if exists)
child_queue_instance_id - value of the child element (if exists)

hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

O(n) is better than O(n^2), right? ;)

I assume that the parent and child id are actually the previous and next id in the list.

First put the items in a dictionary so that you easily can look them up on the `QueueInstanceId`. In this loop you also locate the first item. Then you just add the items to the linked list and use the dictionary to get the next item. Example in C#:

```
Dictionary<int, QueueList> lookup = new Dictionary<int, QueueList>();
QueueList first = null;
foreach (QueueList item in source) {
    lookup.Add(item.QueueInstanceId, item);
    if (item.ParentQueueInstanceId == -1) {
        first = item;
    }
}
LinkedList<QueueList> list = new LinkedList<QueueList>();
do {
    list.AddLast(first);
} while (lookup.TryGetValue(first.ChildQueueInstanceId, out first));
```

Adding items to a dictionary and getting them by key are O(1) operations, and each loop is the length of the source list, so it's all an O(n) operation.

Comment: thank you very much, Guffa. that totally makes sense. that was the solution I was looking for but sometime is hard at he end of the work day...

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this a little bit, you can do it in O(n) time, although it will take some extra stuff that will add some overhead. (Still O(n)).

You could use some sort of universal hashing scheme so that you can build a good hashtable. Essentially, hash by the instance id.

-Take each queue, and throw it into a doubly linked node of some sort.
- Insert each node into the hashtable.
- When you insert, check if the parent and/or child are in the hashtable and link accordingly.
_ when you are done, start at the head (which you should be able to figure out in the first pass), walk the list and add it to your LinkedList or just use the resulting doubly linked list.

This takes one pass that is O(n), and the hashtable takes O(n) to initialize and inserts are O(1).

The problem left for you is choosing a good hashtable implementation that will give you those results.

Also, you have to consider the memory overhead, as I do not know how many results you expect. Hopefully enough to keep in memory.

I don't know of or think there is an SQL query based solution, but my SQL knowledge is very limited.

Hope this helps!